# What is impact of many unused views in Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, view

We are using a standard ERP solution for our niche market. It runs with an Oracle database. The application is using a lot of views, especially for reports. Eg the report "Customer list" is using the view "v_customerList".
When we have a modification of a report, the supplier typically makes an adjustment of the corresponding view in a customer specific version. Such a view gets a customer specific suffix. Eg our own customer list is using "v_customerlist**_abc**". 
With each new version of the application of course we expect that the supplier makes sure 'our' views are updated where needed. So the supplier has a copy of the views and with each release we receive those updated.... BUT
we also receive all the customer specific views of the other users of this application! In total I count 96 different suffix codes and in 697 views that do not belong on my system (like 25 different versions of v_deliverynote).
So my question now is: what are the technical-, security- or oracle arguments to not wanting this?

Comment: There should be no technical problems (performance, resource usage etc.) I would be very concerned about privacy (and perhaps security) though - not from you having other people’s views, but from others having yours. Views are often used to mask some information from some users. If for whatever reason any values are hard-coded in the view (such as: where name != your_undercover_agent_name), that will be visible to other customers who use the same vendor.